MissingMethodException: Method 'Match3.InputReader.OnFire' not found
I meet this error. This is my Player Input and InputReader code, i try to fix error many time but it's not working, so my behavior in Player Input is problem?
enter image description here
enter image description here
I Hope anyone will help me to fix this error, Thanks

Please dont post pictures of code

Convert your code from image to text. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

There is probably a conflict between your class Match3.InputReader and the input actions generated class with the same name Match3 ... So there compiler probably is trying to find InputReader within the Match3 class generated from your input actions asset. Try to rename the input actions to e.g. Match3Input and see if this allows to better differ between the two
